# Can we simulate Pithora art paintings with Point Cloud library?

Tags: google-chrome, camera, point-cloud-library, elasticsearch-painless, onpaint

Given that today there are many PCL enabled cameras, can we simulate a Pithora art painting and do some data analysis? What are the copyright copyleft issues which may come up assuming it is a 5D painting.